# React TypeScript - Exporting more than one component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given this folder structure:

```
├──components/
|  └─Elements/
|    └─Button/
|    └─Input/
|    └─index.ts
|  └─Home/
|    └─home.tsx
```

I would like to export `Button` and `Input` so I can access them from the home component by doing:

home.tsx

```
import { Button, Input } from '@elements/'
```

I have tried this:

index.ts (in Elements folder)

```
export { Button } from './Button/button';
export { Input } from './Input/input';
```

But it does not work, I get: `Cannot find module '@elements/' or its corresponding type declarations.` even thou the resolve alias does work.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../public",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"],
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@images/*": ["src/images/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@elements/*": ["src/components/Elements/*"],
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "webpack"]
}
```

webpack.config.babel.js

```
...
resolve: {
  alias: [
    '@src': join(rootDir, '/src'),
    '@images': join(rootDir, '/src/images'),
    '@assets': join(rootDir, '/src/assets'),
    '@styles': join(rootDir, '/src/styles'),
    '@components': join(rootDir, '/src/components'),
    '@elements': join(rootDir, '/src/components/Elements')
  ]
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

Comment: @elements alias works if I import a single component

Comment: I see, yes it has to do with that I changed it to `../Elements` and now it works

Comment: @T.J Crowder, in TypeScript "paths": { "@elements/*": ["src/components/Elements/*"]} and in webpack resolve: { alias :'@elements': join(rootDir, '/src/components/Elements')...

Comment: @T.J Crowder, I do not understand why it wont work with @elements, it works if I import a single component with `import { Button } from '@elements/Button'`

Comment: I fix it by doing "@elements/*": ["src/components/Elements/"], basically removing the * from the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to be removing the `*` from the `path` declaration on `tsconfig.json`

This

```
"@elements/*": ["src/components/Elements/"]
```

Instead of this

```
"@elements/*": ["src/components/Elements/*"]
```

And then importing it by using

```
import { Button, Input } from '@elements/'
```

or

```
"@elements": ["src/components/Elements"]
```

```
import { Button, Input } from '@elements'
```

Comment: That worked for me as well. Since [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) shows those `*` in the target, I suggest raising a [documentation bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

Comment: @Alvaro Is this correct `"@src/*": ["src*"],` ? I mean it should be `["src/*"]` ?

Comment: Subro, you are correct, I never really used the @src alias but it was wrong

Comment: @Alvaro `import { Button, Input } from '@elements'` Have you tried removing `/` in the non-relative import? I am asking this because in the alias it is resolved as `@elements`. Let me know does that work.

Comment: I have edited the answer to address just that

Comment: Oh thats works too  I would go with 2nd approach. Btw nice config file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Button } from './Button/button';
import { Input } from './Input/input';
```

should probably be

```
export { Button } from './Button/button';
export { Input } from './Input/input';
```

If they are default exports, you have to do this.

```
export { default as Button } from './Button/button';
export { default as Input } from './Input/input';
```

Answer (score 0):

`Module resolution` in Typescript is the process that the compiler uses to figure out what an import refers to. You can read more on `module resolution` in the [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

```
import { Button } from './Button/button';
```

This type of import is called a `relative import`. A relative import is one that starts with /, ./ or ../.

Any other import is considered non-relative. Some examples include:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
```

---

There is two module resolution strategy in typescript which is `node` and `classic`. By default module resolution is set to `classic`.

Set the module resolution to `node` would solve your problem.

```
"moduleResoution": "node"
```

> Note: node module resolution is the most-commonly used in the TypeScript community and is recommended for most projects. If you are having resolution problems with imports and exports in TypeScript, try setting `moduleResolution: "node"` to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Setting `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `tsconfig.json` didn't fix this for me.

Comment: @Subro, thanks for the response, I already have `"moduleResolution": "node"` on my `tsconfig`, but still if I import a single component it works but not with two

Comment: Did you get it to work with @elements and with two components?

Comment: @Álvaro - (If that was in response to my saying I couldn't get it to work even with one component in my non-deleted comment.) No, I can't get it to work with one component, two components, etc. I figure there's just something I'm missing, though, TS config isn't my strong suit.